# segmentation fault in pi calculation (python)

Tags: python, for-loop, segmentation-fault, series, pi

```
def pi(times):
    seq = []
    counter = 0
    for x in range(times):
        counter += 2
        seq.append("((%f**2)/(%f*%f))*"%(float(counter), float(counter-1), float(counter+1)))
    seq.append("1.0")
    seq = "".join(seq)
    seq = eval(seq)
    return seq*2
```

Anywhere past 85000 terms I get a segmentation fault and python quits. How can I avoid this? Why is it crashing? Can't it just *please* use more memory or something?

Comment: [gnu debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: so i can get it to interpret the string.

Comment: Why are you doing the calculation that way, instead of just doing a running calculation as you figure out the terms? Also, why are you reusing `seq` for the joined string and the evaluated result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have found a bug in `eval` where it can't handle insanely long expressions:

```
>>> eval("1.0*"*10000+"1.0")
1.0
>>> eval("1.0*"*100000+"1.0")
# segfault here
```

I use the phrase "insanely long" advisedly though. Don't do it that way, calculate the pieces as you go. There is no reason to be using `eval` in this situation.

Comment: wow thank you :) now I'm getting a syntaxerror when trying to return seq as an int, calculating on the fly

Comment: i cannot believe i didn't calculate on the fly instead of using eval :O

Comment: I've seen something about this before and it isn't really considered a bug so much as the programmer abusing eval.

Comment: The segfault outcome is a bug. Simply declaring an expression that long to be unreasonable and refusing to accept it would be OK, but it should raise an exception in that case.

Comment: Ah, it was a known defect, it just didn't have a tracker item.

Answer (score 2):

Why use `eval()` at all?

```
def pi(times):
    val = 1
    counter = 0
    for x in range(times) :
        counter += 2
        val *= float(counter)**2/(counter**2 - 1)
    return val * 2
```

Does the exact same thing.