# Why is there a length limit to python's eval?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, eval

I'm not advocating that this would ever be a good idea, but I've found that you can crash Python (2.7 and 3.2 checked) by running `eval` on a large enough input string:

```
def kill_python(N):
    S = '+'.join((str(n) for n in xrange(N)))
    return eval(S)
```

On my computer `S` can be generated just fine, but for values of approximately `N>74900`,  Python will fail with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Is there a limit to the length of string (or parse tree) that the interpreter can handle?

**Note**: I don't *need* to do this, to me this is a deeper question reflecting my ignorance of what goes on inside the box. I'd like to understand why Python fails here, and so catastrophically (why not throw an exception?)

Comment: IIRC, the Python interpreter segfaulting is considered a bug in any situation, and shouldn't happen - this might be worth a [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: @Lattyware: In most situations, not all.  But this one *should* be considered a bug.

Comment: Interestingly, `sum(xrange(75000))` seems to work just fine

Comment: @SvenMarnach A few exceptions spring to mind (the most obvious being an extension module causing CPython to crash), but as this is core functionality, I think - as you say - it's probably a bug.

Comment: I just tested `N=749001` - It worked fine... as did 750000.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this effect at `N = 74900`

Comment: @mutzmatron: The limit on my machine is also much higher than Hooked's value, but eventually it segfaults.

Comment: @mutzmatron I think it may be computer dependent. Try larger values of `N` and see if you can get it to crash - I looped my function until I found the fail value.

Comment: The same thing happens using `exec`, or even when writing the string to a file and trying to run it.

Comment: Cheers @SvenMarnach - got it now too.

Comment: Could it be that the resultant string from the `join` takes up more memory than the OP's computer has?

Comment: This has been seen in the answer here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177432/segmentation-fault-in-pi-calculation-python

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: When I ran the function, I used `print` to indicate where the segfault is occuring. The string formation doesn't cause the crash, it happens on the `eval` line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This issue is caused by a stack overflow in the CPython compiler.  An easy way to reproduce the same issue is

```
>>> code = compile("1" + "+1" * 1000000, "", "eval")
Segmentation fault
```

which proves that the segfault is happening at the compile stage, not during evaluation.  (Of course this is also easy to confirm with gdb.)

[Side note: For smaller expressions, the compiler would apply constant folding here anyway, so the only thing happening during the execution of the code is to load the result:

```
>>> code = compile("1" + "+1" * 1000, "", "eval")
>>> eval(code)
1001
>>> dis.dis(code)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST            1000 (1001)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

End of side note.]

This issue is a [known defect](http://bugs.python.org/issue11383).  The Python developers collected several ways to crash the Python interpreter in the [directory `Lib/test/crashers`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9a881b0d6ca/Lib/test/crashers) of the source distribution.  The one corresponding to this issue is [`Lib/test/crashers/compiler_recursion.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d9a881b0d6ca/Lib/test/crashers/compiler_recursion.py).

Comment: Just for the reference, this seems to be fixed in Python 3.3+. The code raises `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation` now.