# Format string in python for conversion to nump array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, format

I receive strings as follows that I need to save and then convert back to numpy arrays later

```
[0.46619281 -0.79148525  0.20800316 -0.16633733  1.53767002]
[ 0.53119281 -0.79148525  0.20800316 -0.16633733  1.53762345 ]
```

Note how the second line has a space after the first [ and before the last ]

How can I format the string to change it so that it does not have this space before and after the brackets?

I need a consistent  way to store the arrays as strings so I can then convert them back again as detailed in this post:
[Convert string containg array of floats to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871598/convert-string-containg-array-of-floats-to-numpy-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = s.replace('[','').replace(']','').split()
a = list(map(int, a))
```

Comment: This creates class 'list'>: [0.53119281, -0.79148525,  0.20800316, -0.16633733,  1.53762345] where there are commas between numbers.  How can get it as a string similar to my examples?

Answer (score 0):

The best professional step is to enforce the sources, that "produce" the different strings, to re-factor their code so as to uniformly adhere to your defined API for string-representation of array(s).

If you trust the sources and want to rely on un-coordinated formats, use an explicit ex-post transformation:

```
>>> "[ ............ ] [....... ]".replace( "[ ", "[" ).replace( " ]", "]" )
'[............] [.......]'
```